# What should I use instead of navigator.getBattery()

Tags: javascript, battery, batterylevel

**I am looking for a navigator.getBattery() alternative.** What I want to achieve is, that when you have under 30% of battery and you're not charging, it tells you to go charge. Right now I have this:

```
navigator.getBattery().then(function(battery) {
    if (battery.level < 0.3 && battery.charging === false) {
        let goCharge = document.createElement('h1');
        goCharge.style.fontSize = '40px';
        goCharge.style.color = '#FF0101';
        goCharge.textContent = 'GO CHARGE YOUR DEVICE NOW!';
        document.body.appendChild(goCharge);
        document.title = 'GO CHARGE YOUR DEVICE NOW!';
        document.getElementById('ico').href = 'battery_alert.png';
        alert('GO CHARGE YOUR DEVICE NOW!');
        throw new Error('GO CHARGE YOUR DEVICE NOW!');
    }
});
```

The problem is, that Firefox (and Safari) doesn't support this. And while I was looking for a Firefox alternative, I found many sites (e.g. [1](https://contest-server.cs.uchicago.edu/ref/JavaScript/developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getBattery.html), [2](https://udn.realityripple.com/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getBattery)) saying, that I should no longer use it. I couldn't find any other way to get the battery info.

If someone knows a solution, please share your idea with me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: doubt you will find it since most browsers did not implement or removed it due to security reasons.

Comment: So does that mean, that there is **no** intended, not deprecated way to get the battery level?

Comment: Safari never supported because Apple want to prevent web-apps from becoming too powerful (forcing devs to create native apps).
That Firefox dropped it is . . . And the Mozilla team is wondering why Firefox adoption is dropping.

The only future I see is that you have a local server providing you that via native APIs or a new spec that requests a permission like you have for location or notifications.